# Reactのコンポーネントが制御か非制御かはどのようにして決まる？

Tags: reactjs

Reactについて勉強中です。

Reactの制御コンポーネントと非制御コンポーネントについてわからない点があります。
Reactのあるコンポーネントが制御か非制御かはどのようにして決まるのでしょうか？

公式ドキュメントをみるとrefを使用するかどうかで決まるのかという印象を受けました。
他にも何か基準があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

私は以下で両者の違いを理解しています。

- 制御コンポーネント：　フォームデータをReactのコンポーネントで扱う(`useState`などコンポーネントで管理する。)
- 非制御コンポーネント：フォームデータをDOM自身が扱う(`ref`を使ってその値を取得する)

"公式ドキュメントを見ると"とあるのですでに読んでいるかと思いますが、参考リンク貼っておきます。

- https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html
- https://goshacmd.com/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Comment: TK'さんありがとうございます。
ちなみに制御コンポーネントはuseStateやuseContextなどで管理されているコンポーネントという認識で合っていますでしょうか？

Comment: その認識で大丈夫だと思います。

以下の記事は、フォームライブラリのreact-hook-form（非制御コンポーネントでフォーム管理するライブラリ）を紹介する記事ですが、その中に”How to Create a Form Without Using a Library”というセクションがあって、ここで制御コンポーネントとしてフォームを扱っているサンプルコードがありますので、制御・非制御の違い等参考になるかと思います。

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-forms-in-react-using-react-hook-form/

Answer (score 0):

ref にはあんまり関係ないですかね

最新のBeta docのこちらをご覧ください

https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components

> You might say a component is “controlled” when the important information in it is driven by props rather than its own local state.

Comment: keikaiさんありがとうございます。リンク先の情報拝見しましたが、uncontrolledはローカルなstateで管理されているような（親が影響できない）状態のコンポーネントのことを指していて、controlledはpropsなど親が影響できる状態のコンポーネントのことを指しているという認識で合っていますか？そうすると例えば親子間でグローバルなstate管理（useContext/createContext)しているようなコンポーネントはおそらくcontorolledになるのかなと考えたのですが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: はい！ 合っていると思います！